# Failng to display "data saved" message in the front end

Tags: php, javascript

I am converting all the values from xml to CSV successfully in the 2nd page(Export page). But i want to display a message "data converted successfully" in the first page(seat-matrix ).

I am failing to display the message in seat-matrix.php (1st page). Please help me.

In "Seatmatrix.php" file I have the following code.

```
<form name="export" action="export.php">
<input type="submit" name = "export"  value="Export" title ='Exports all the above info to excel'> 
</form>
```

In export.php file I have alert function and included header function to redirect to seat-matrix page as show below.

```
<?php  
echo "
<html>
<head>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='javascript'>
function Result() {
alert (\"Data exported successfully\");
}
</SCRIPT>
</head>
<body>
";

// export feature code

echo "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='javascript'>Result();</SCRIPT>\n";
header('location:Seat_matrix.php');

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler way would be to post the result back to the original page and have it check. You would need to change your code to something like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['result']) {
    if ($_GET['result'] == "success") {
        echo "Data exported successfully.");
    }
    else {
        echo "Error exporting data.";
    }
}
<form name="export" action="export.php">
<input type="submit" name = "export"  value="Export" title ='Exports all the above info to excel'> 
</form>
```

And in the other code add the result variable to the url:

```
header('location:Seat_matrix.php?result=success');
```

Summary:

The first time you call Seat_matrix.php, there is no result variable and it program runs at it does now. Once the second program is executed, it calls back Seat_matrix.php and passess the variable result. The second time Seat_matrix.php is called, it checks if the result variable was passed and shows the message. You will probably have to play a little bit with the location where you want the message.

I hope this helps. Good luck!

***Edit***

To get rid of the $_GET variable after you write the success message, you could try something like:

```
if (isset($_GET['result']) {
    if ($_GET['result'] == "success") {
        echo "Data exported successfully.");
    }
    else {
        echo "Error exporting data.";
    }
    unset ($_GET);
}
```

I haven't tested the above method, but I believe it might work.

Comment: Hi this works perfectly but after displaying the "Data exported successfully" message. If i reload the page the message still remains. because browsser still has Seat_matrix.php?result=success'.

Comment: I mean when i click new button the message still remains. I am using below code       <INPUT TYPE="button" onClick="history.go(0)" VALUE="New" title ='Add a new cubicle'>

Comment: You could try changing your onClick to onClick="parent.location='http://www.example.com/Seat_matrix.php'" this way it would call the page without any variable... I believe this might work.

Comment: well that might be not good idea as we need to hard code the folder name right.. bec in server the path will be different

Comment: another option might be to use unset ($_GET); I haven't tried it, but it might work. Just add it to the code... see my revision. It might work.

Comment: @vinod - actually I have just tested and you don't need the full path. You could use onClick="parent.location='Seat_matrix.php'" and it works. It removes the $_GET variable.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't get run until the browser gets it. Because of the header redirect it will never get run in the browser.

Your best bet is to set a session variable, then check if it is set in Seat_matrix.php. If it is, add your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to do the redirect instead:

```
<SCRIPT type='text/javascript'>
    alert ('Data exported successfully');
    window.location = 'Seat_matrix.php';
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: hi this works fine but page remains blank when it pop-up.. So i am thinking to use sessions..